# WorkManager - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, androidx, android-workmanager

Getting this error while using work manager,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
   at androidx.work.impl.utils.c.<init> (EnqueueRunnable.java:3)
   at androidx.work.impl.f.a (WorkContinuationImpl.java:2)
   at androidx.work.impl.m.a (WorkManagerImpl.java:16)
   at androidx.work.p.a (WorkManager.java:4)
```

this code runs on `BootReceiver`.

`implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0'`

have also tried

`implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.0.1'`

The project has,

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Have already checked if there are any conflicting version on `dependency tree`

Am i doing something wrong with proguard config?

**Edit**
 Here is the code,

```
val work = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(A::class.java).build()
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(work)
```

Usual one.

I'm starting to suspect on kotlin version, hence reverted it to `1.3.30` from `1.3.31`.

Also on build tools,
Reverting to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
```

**Edit2:**
Changing build tools and kotlin doesn't fix it.

Haven't got it fixed yet. Any hints?

Comment: Can you add the code of your worker class?
Be sure that it is defined as public.

Comment: @pfmaggi based on your comment, i suspected it could be because of kotlin version and have reverted it back.

Comment: have you tried `implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
` for kotlin specific.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#declaring_dependencies

Comment: @UmarHussain i dont have coroutine code in my project. Will try and let the result know here